# kotlin Android studio tablayout

Tags: android, tabs, kotlin

- Question 1) How to delete the border line of the tablayout?
- Question 2) How to set the padding for the action bar icon?

[image]

Here with the code in activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here with the code I wrote in the Main_Activity.kt file:

//Action Bar

```
 val actionBar = supportActionBar
actionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF")))
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.title)
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could create a custom layout for your action bar that lets you control how the icon will look. However due to the millions of problems that you will encounter doing that, can I suggest you move from using `ActionBar` to its successor, the `Toolbar`, introduced in API 21, which you should be using:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar

You can easily introduced a fully customizable Toolbar within your `CoordinatorLayout`, and do cool things thanks to the design library.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/qpon_drawable"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image]

I can add any margins I want, and taking the `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` it has no start padding. You can add the toolbar as a support action bar in your code:

```
    // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
    // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

2. I had the same problem of a border when I set the background color of the `AppBarLayout` as transparent:

[image]

When I set the `AppBarLayout's` background to the same colour as the background, it seems to draw over the edges and the border disappears. Bear in mind that it automatically gives it a shadow in the bottom since it is above the content of the `Viewpager`:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- This is what you want to change !-->
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

[image]

No more border edges on the side. I don't quite know why it does that, it seems to be like it is a card layout in its natural form if you don't color over it.

Hope it helps. No matter your reasoning, do try to change to the Toolbar I think that is the only right answer!